# ¿Como puedo listar de un serializador en django rest framework relaciones de muchos a muchos?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Los serializers funcionan bastante bien, pero no puedo hacer que me retorne mi json los nombres de esas relaciones, solo me retorna los id

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize a recipe"""
      ingredients = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
                    many=True,
                    queryset=Ingredient.objects.all()
    )
      tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
          many=True,
          queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'ingredients', 'time_minutes', 'tags',
              'price', 'link',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Y asi me retorna la información:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "comida china",
        "ingredients": [
            1,
            2,
            4
        ],
        "time_minutes": 5,
        "tags": [
            3
        ],
        "price": "50.00",
        "link": ""
    }
]
```

Desearía que en vez de mostrarme de ingredients los 'id', me mostrara los nombres 'name'

Nota: He intentado con to_representation return { 'id': instance.ingredient.name } y me da como resultado NULL, no lo se quiza todo sea por que es una lista, pero no sabria como representarla, el campo si existe pero aparece NULL

Answer (score 0):

Es normal esa respuesta por que estas usando el serializador PrimaryRelatedField, para obtener lo que quieres, debes crear otro serializador con la estructura que quieres que el server responda, y luego llamarla remplazando en el PrimaryRelatedField:

```
class IngredientsModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  fiels = '__all__'

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ingredients IngredientsModelSerializer(many=True)
```

El codigo anterior es mas una referencia de lo que puedes hacer para lograrlo, pero es la idea general